# Why does $k r= \omega t$ describe a sphere?

Tags: physics, spheres

I'm struggling to understand the solution of the following question:

---

"The real electric field of the simplest monochromatic spherical wave in the source free vacuum which is allowed by Maxwell Theory is:"

$$E(r, \theta, \phi, t)= A \frac{\sin \theta}{r}[\cos (kr- \omega t)-(kr)^{-1} \sin{(kr- \omega t)}]n_{\phi}$$

"Show that the surfaces of constant phase are spheres"

---

The solution simply claims "The condition constant phase kr = ωt is the definition equation of a sphere". $k = \frac{2 \pi }{\lambda}$ is the wave number, $\omega = 2 \pi f$ the angular frequency, $t$ the time and $r$ the radius. I really have some troubles understanding how $k r= \omega t$ really describes a sphere. Any help/ hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more context as to what's going on. Are you studying electromagnetic waves?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yeah. We are given an electric field $A \frac{\sin \theta}{r} \cos (kr- \omega t) $. The question they ask us is: "Show that the surfaces of constant phase are spheres", and as solution, they simply say $kr = \omega t$ describes in fact a sphere. Does that help ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I just edited my question. Is it more clear now ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could I reask the question otherwise now that it's more precise, and delete this one ?